# Combining huge data sets in R

Tags: r, loops, memory, large-data

I am new to working with huge data sets in R. So I appreciate any help
I have 20 years of data, and for each year three .csv files, each file size is about 3 GB
I tried function list.files() to store the names of files in a vector
and now I know theoretically I need to loop along this vector to read the files and generate integrals one by one  and also combine the files. But i don't know how I can loop along and combine my data sets or run different models!!!! Constantly i get error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.4 Gb" or "Memory is exhausted, reached the limit"!!!!!!!
I would be thankful if anybody could guide me.
Best regards
Sara

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure that your computer has enough RAM memory and storage to work with this amount of data. fread() is a very useful function to wrangle data fastly. Try it : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/fread.

If that doesn't work, then try spark. It's very fast, convenient and simple. You don't need to know it, just check this cheat sheet (https://ugoproto.github.io/ugo_r_doc/pdf/sparklyr.pdf). Best of luck!

Comment: thanks for your help. My laptop has 16 GB of RAM. now I'm trying to clean up the memory by gc() after every time loading data and then continue with the next step.